# Referring to supervisors/advisors in internship (Similar to French terms "promoteur" and "maitre de stage")

Tags: word-choice

I am starting to draft the writing of my internship report which I do in English. On first page, I must mention two names: the one of the professor who must have an eye on me during the intership *("promoteur"* in French) and the one of the person who is responsible of me inside the company *("maitre de stage"* in French).

How would you express those ideas?

Equivalent to *"Promoteur":* sponsor, proponent, or perhaps promoter ?

Equivalent to *"Maître de stage":* internship supervisor, adviser, articling supervisor, tutor ?

Comment: Don't take my word for it (I know little about internships), but I suspect "promoteur" equates to ***sponsor***, and your definition of "Maître de stage" looks a lot like what I'd probably call your ***mentor*** (or maybe ***tutor*** or ***supervisor***).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about translation are specifically mentioned as off-topic in the help centre [vide](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This is not simply or even mainly a translation question. It could have just as  easily have been asked without mentioning the French terms.

Comment: I agree with @JimReynolds. The OP could have said: What's a word for someone who has an eye on me during the internship? Or such.

Comment: So a question asking ***How would you translate those terms ?** "Promoteur": sponsor, proponent, or perhaps promoter ? "Maître de stage": internship supervisor, adviser, articling supervisor, tutor ?* is not a question about translation. Pardon me, but bull shit.

Comment: In addition, the two extant questions are all about comparing French words to English ones. Oh, I guess comparing is not translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, *professor (or instructor)* or *advisor* are probably most common for *promoteur.* *Sponsor* also sounds appropriate, and might be used as well.

An internship is usually a special kind of course. So it has an instructor or professor.

[An example from Univ of CA, San Diego uses **faculty supervisor**:](http://aip.ucsd.edu/faculty/faculty-advisor-role.html)

> The Academic Internship Program is a Special Studies Course, AIP 197.  As such, a **faculty advisor** is required for all students participating in an AIP internship. Faculty Advisors help students create a structure to investigate a particular research question related to the internship, and guide students in developing a paper or project to address their research interest.

In my experience *supervisor* is used for *Maître de stage.* And that's true for the [example program I referenced above](http://aip.ucsd.edu/employers/post.html):

> AIP is an academic program, so participating organizations must adhere to the policies and procedures outlined in AIP's **Supervisor** Guidelines.

I worked as a university administrator for a couple of years, so I base this on some professional experience. I also know that different countries, schools, and companies/employers will use different terms.

Comment: I asked the question to a friend who just did an internship in Boston. He used the terms compagny's supervisor and academic supervisor there. As you said it may vary from a school to another and from a compagny to another. Thanks for your answer.